# accepts form even if 1 input is invalid php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple registration form but, when I input a first name as a "123" or leave it blank and the last name having a normal string w/o nums, the form still accepts it as a valid data. but if I enter the "123" at the last name but a real name on the first_name. I get the appropriate response for this. any idea?

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = array();
    if (empty($_POST['first_name']) || is_numeric($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "Invalid First Name";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    if (empty($_POST['last_name']) || is_numeric($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "Invalid Last Name";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: process.php");
    }
```

Comment: You might want to have an `exit` after the `header` it seems, though I don't see how the behavior described follows. You could also just have the errors redirection after all your conditions, so you'd log all fails in one go, instead of redirecting at the first error. As in, `if(!empty($_SESSION['errors'])) { header...`.

Comment: Side-answer `is_numeric` will return false with for example 'Simone123', if you need only character use `preg_match` instead.

Comment: The 2nd location header replaces the first - so when invalid first name and valid second name the header location of `process.php` is used.